# How to create a date range in boost datetime?

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

I would like to create a range of timestamps, between a start date and end date and a chosen frequency. For example given these parameters as start date, end date and the frequency:

```
2002-01-20 23:59:59.000
2002-01-21 04:59:59.000
Freq = Hour
```

It should return a vector/list of timestamps:

```
2002-01-21 00:00:00.000
2002-01-21 01:00:00.000
2002-01-21 02:00:00.000
2002-01-21 03:00:00.000
2002-01-21 04:00:00.000
```

Does the `Boost:date_time` library have a function to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost has two related things:

- [`time_period`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#date_time.posix_time.time_period)
- [time iterators](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#date_time.posix_time.time_iterators)

The first literally gives you a date-range. The second is what you were looking for I think.

### `time_period`:

Sample:

```
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::posix_time;
using namespace boost::gregorian;

struct day_period : time_period {
    day_period(date d) : time_period(ptime(d), ptime(d, hours(24))) {}
};

int main() {
    const date d(2002, Feb, 1); // an arbitrary date
    const day_period dp(d); // the containing day

    ptime t(d, hours(3) + seconds(5)); // an arbitray time on that day

    if (dp.contains(t)) {
        std::cout << to_simple_string(dp) << " contains " << to_simple_string(t) << std::endl;
    }

    // a period that represents part of the day
    time_period part_of_day(ptime(d, hours(0)), t);

    // intersect the 2 periods and print the results
    if (part_of_day.intersects(dp)) {

        time_period result = part_of_day.intersection(dp);

        std::cout 
            << to_simple_string(dp) << " intersected with\n"
            << to_simple_string(part_of_day) << " is \n"
            << to_simple_string(result) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
[2002-Feb-01 00:00:00/2002-Feb-01 23:59:59.999999999]
contains 2002-Feb-01 03:00:05
[2002-Feb-01 00:00:00/2002-Feb-01 23:59:59.999999999]
intersected with
[2002-Feb-01 00:00:00/2002-Feb-01 03:00:04.999999999]
is
[2002-Feb-01 00:00:00/2002-Feb-01 03:00:04.999999999]
```

### Time Iterators

Sample:

```
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace boost::gregorian;
    using namespace boost::posix_time;

    ptime start(date(2000, Jan, 20)), end = start + hours(1);

    time_iterator titr(start, minutes(15)); // increment by 15 minutes

    // produces 00:00:00, 00:15:00, 00:30:00, 00:45:00
    while (titr < end) {
        std::cout << to_simple_string(*titr) << std::endl;
        ++titr;
    }

    std::cout << "Now backward" << std::endl;
    // produces 01:00:00, 00:45:00, 00:30:00, 00:15:00
    while (titr > start) {
        std::cout << to_simple_string(*titr) << std::endl;
        --titr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes time_iterator is exactly what I want.